# How to set item to center of RecyclerView when using scrollToPosition

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I am using a RecyclerView to display items horizontally.

I want that when i use scrollToPosition(position), the respective item appears on the center not on the left.

Does anyone has any idea how to do it? I know how to do it using smoothScrollToPosition, but in this case i need to do it with scrollToPosition.

[image: RecyclerView exemple]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Consider using [`scrollToPositionWithOffset(int position, int offset)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/LinearLayoutManager.html#scrollToPositionWithOffset(int,%20int)) and passing required offset as you wish from left. You can find your required offset by using the width of the parent layout (assuming you are using horizontal recycler view). cheers :)

Comment: No, It doesn't have any effect when using scrollToPosition. It helps to center only when performing scrolling gestures on the RecyclerView.

Comment: why you want to use ScrollToposition?

Comment: I have a recyclerView which appears on the screen when i double click, i need that it shows a concrete item centered, from the start.

Comment: but its not moving with animation, what solution is there if i want to make same thing with animation?

Comment: @sAndroidD As a workaround, you can add some empty rows before first item and after last item. good luck (Y)

Comment: how to calculate offset?